# Child to parent SOQL query inside a parent to child query

Tags: soql, query, subquery

I need a query to get the Name of the records referenced in the WhatId and OwnerId fields of the ActivityHistories related to a contact. How can I go about bulding this query? This is what I have so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When doing joins that pull in parent fields, you need to use the `Relationship Name` of the field, not its `API Name`. In this case, `OwnerId` should instead be `Owner`, and `WhatId` should instead be `What`. Unfortunately, joins typically do not work on polymorphic fields, and I am fairly sure `What.Name` will still fail. It is, however, the only correct field path.