# Soql to query parent fields inside of a child query which is a parent - child query

Tags: soql

I am trying to retrieve the parent fields of a child object which is already inside of a parent to child query. I do understand that the retrieving polymorphic fields dont work on joins based on this post [Child to parent SOQL query inside a parent to child query](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/357001/child-to-parent-soql-query-inside-a-parent-to-child-query).

In my case I am not pulling any polymorphic fields just the custom fields of the custom object. I am not getting any errors on the query, so I believe I am using the right relationship names to access the fields.

Here is the query -

```
SELECT Id, CaseNumber,(SELECT Equipment__c, Equipment__r.Name, Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Items__r) FROM Case where CaseNumber ='00001026'
```

Here is the result of the query for which I am getting Object Object for the Equipment__r.Name & Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c  fields -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is being returned, but the Developer Console's Query tab doesn't support grandparent (or higher) parent relationships, or relationships from child objects. Try using the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) instead.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox for the reminder.